# Renamed XCode project and now app won't load

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, save, rename

I'm making a game with swift and I went into the project editor to rename the project. Now when I try to run it it just gives me a gray screen. My app is called Scene Transition, and under the projects folder the Scene Transition.app and Scene Transition Tests.xctest are both red. Not sure if this has something to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest following the instructions in [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHr1vjkTxC0).  In general, renaming things in Xcode without considering the configuration changes is a bad idea (this actually holds for just about every programming language and environment I can think of).